# Laravel - Oops no page available

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a project in Laravel and I have a page with links.

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level">
    <li>
        <a href="{{route('admin.posts.index')}}">All Posts</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{route('admin.posts.create')}}">Create Post</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{route('admin.comments.index')}}">All Comments</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem I have is that when I click on the link:

```
<a href="{{route('admin.posts.create')}}">Create Post</a>
```

I get the error:

> Oops no page found

These are my routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function() {

    Route::get('/admin', function(){
        return view('admin.index');
    });

    Route::get('/admin/posts/{slug}', 'AdminPostsController@post')->name('posts.post');

    Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
    Route::resource('admin/posts', 'AdminPostsController');
    Route::resource('admin/categories', 'AdminCategoriesController');
    Route::resource('admin/media', 'AdminMediasController');
    Route::resource('admin/comments', 'PostCommentsController');
    Route::resource('admin/comment/replies', 'CommentRepliesController');

});
```

Comment: Do the other links work? I wonder if it's in the `'as' => '...'` area...

Comment: Is the url in your browser correct? For instance if you are in the route /user and you click a link to goto /admin is it going to user/admin instead of /admin?

Comment: I've never seen the use of `as` in a `Route::group` before. Is that actually supported behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `admin.posts.create` route will evaluate to `admin/posts/create`. The problem, however, is this route definition:

```
Route::get('/admin/posts/{slug}', 'AdminPostsController@post')->name('posts.post');
```

Because this route is defined before your `admin/posts` resource route, `admin/posts/create` will not match the `create` resource action, but will instead match the `post` action, where `{slug}` evaluates as "create". I'm guessing the "Oops no page found" message is your own error message because your `post` action is not expecting to handle a "create" slug.

I believe moving that route definition after your resource route definitions (or, at least after the `admin/posts` resource definition) should resolve your issue.

Comment: @johndraks21 Thinking about it again, this may cause a different issue. The resource `show` route will be defined as `/admin/posts/{post}`, which will take precedence over your custom `/admin/posts/{slug}` route. This will fix your `create` route issue, but are you sure you can still reach your slug route?

Comment: I fixed that by putting showBySlug before the {slug} in the uri like this: '/admin/posts/showBySlug/{slug}'